# how to pass an integer as ConverterParameter?

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I am trying to bind to an integer property:

```
<RadioButton Content="None"
             IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty,
                         Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter},
                         ConverterParameter=0}" />
```

and my converter is:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(bool))]
public class IntToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(false) ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue : parameter;
    }
}
```

the problem is that when my converter is called the parameter is string. i need it to be an integer. of course i can parse the string, but do i have to?

thanks for any help
konstantin

Comment: Does anybody know how to achive this on Windows Phone platform where we have slightly different syntax for bindings?

    {Binding PROPERTY, Converter={StaticResource MYCONVERTER}, ConverterParameter=INT_VAL}

in this example INT_VAL will be passed as a string

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Here ya go!

```
<RadioButton Content="None"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <RadioButton.IsChecked>
        <Binding Path="MyProperty"
                 Converter="{StaticResource IntToBoolConverter}">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </RadioButton.IsChecked>
</RadioButton>
```

The trick is to include the namespace for the basic system types and then to write at least the ConverterParameter binding in element form.

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that the type of `IValueConverter.Convert()`'s *"parameter"* parameter is `object`. You still have to cast/parse it...

Comment: @djacobson - True but that is what the ValueConversion attribute allows you to specify. Not exactly sure whether this is really used by at compile-time or run-time at all. In terms of the original posters question he specified that "i need it to be an integer. of course i can parse the string, but do i have to?" So my answer alleviates that in that there is no parsing of a string but only the unboxing of an integer which I is still much more safe.

Answer (score 63):

For completeness, one more possible solution (perhaps with less typing):

```
<Window
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="IntZero">0</sys:Int32>
    </Window.Resources>

    <RadioButton Content="None"
                 IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty,
                                     Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter},
                                     ConverterParameter={StaticResource IntZero}}" />
```

(Of course, `Window` can be replaced with `UserControl`, and `IntZero` may be defined closer to the place of actual usage.)

Answer (score 58):

Not sure why `WPF` folks tend to be disinclined towards using `MarkupExtension`. It is the perfect solution for many problems including the issue mentioned here.

```
public sealed class Int32Extension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Int32Extension(int value) { this.Value = value; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public override Object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp) { return Value; }
};
```

If this markup extension is defined in `XAML` namespace '`local:`', then the original poster's example becomes:

```
<RadioButton Content="None"
             IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty,
                         Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter},
                         ConverterParameter={local:Int32 0}}" />
```

This works because the markup extension parser can see the strong type of the constructor argument and convert accordingly, whereas Binding's ConverterParameter argument is (less-informatively) Object-typed.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful. It will be my first XAML extension. But I think it's better to make `Value` an `object` rather than `int`, to avoid boxing it each time in `ProvideValue`. (And then, make it `private` to avoid assigning something illegal directly).

Comment: @Zeus Typically `ProvideValue` is only called once per markup extension instance, so the boxing should only occur once anyway. By not doing it in the constructor, I avoid boxing altogether if `ProvideValue` is never called. As for making `Value` private, this would preclude using the markup extension in `XAML` object element syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723(v=vs.100).aspx#object_element_syntax

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong. It's called type conversion and it also applies to properties. The thing is, that `Binding.ConverterParameter` has no specific type (it's just an `object`) so the parser does not know what conversion to apply, hence every literal is just treated as a string.

Comment: (So if you extension had a default constructor, then `{m:Int32 Value=0}` would work just as well.)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `value.Equals`. Use:

```
  Convert.ToInt32(value) == Convert.ToInt32(parameter)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `value.Equals`?

Comment: Because the Value may be null (If it is nullable type) causing ArgumentNullException Error.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to somehow express the type information for the ConverterValue in XAML, but I don't think it is possible as of now. So I guess you have to parse the Converter Object to your expected type by some custom logic. I don't see another way.