# Generically replace Converter in MultiBinding node

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, multibinding

I have some [`RadioButton’s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.radiobutton.aspx) that I want to change the [`Visibility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588755(v=vs.85).aspx) of based on multiple properties in the `ViewModel`.  Each `RadioButton’s` Visibility will vary based on the same list of properties.  I have the following xaml:

```
<RadioButton Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}"
             CommandParameter="SomeCommandParameter"
             Content="RB 1">
   <RadioButton.Visibility>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Rb1Visibility}">
         <Binding Path="Value1"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
         <Binding Path="Value2"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </RadioButton.Visibility>
</RadioButton>
```

I would like to change the `Converter` for each `RadioButton` option, but everything else would remain the same (all the Bindings).  I don’t want to duplicate all the xaml code for this.  I originally tried creating a style for the RadioButton, but I could not figure out how to pass the Converter to the Style resource:

```
<Style x:Key="RbVisibilityStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility">
      <Setter.Value>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{???? Pass in converter ?????}">
            <Binding Path="Value1"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="Value2"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
         </MultiBinding>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

I could create a “Visibility” property for each `RadioButton` in the ViewModel, but that adds a lot of code to the ViewModel and addition `PropertyChanged` event handling.
Is there an easy way to generically bubble up the MultiBinding so I don’t duplicate the code throughout the entire xaml file?  Is there a different approach I should be taking?

**Update - Adding a more complex example**

```
<RadioButton Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}"
             CommandParameter="SomeCommandParameter"
             Content="RB 1">
   <RadioButton.Visibility>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Rb1Visibility}">
         <Binding Path="Value1"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
         <Binding Path="Value2"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </RadioButton.Visibility>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand2}"
             CommandParameter="SomeCommandParameter2"
             Content="RB 2">
   <RadioButton.Visibility>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Rb2Visibility}">
         <Binding Path="Value1"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
         <Binding Path="Value2"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </RadioButton.Visibility>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand3}"
             CommandParameter="SomeCommandParameter3"
             Content="RB 3">
   <RadioButton.Visibility>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Rb3Visibility}">
         <Binding Path="Value1"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
         <Binding Path="Value2"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </RadioButton.Visibility>
</RadioButton>
```

How do I reduce the `MultiBinding` redundancy here?

Comment: Have you tried Value Converter where you could write your logic and return the Visibility

Comment: @D_Learning - Thats what `Rb1Visibility` does.  It returns the `Visibility` based on `Value1` and `Value2`.  The implementation would be different for each `RadioButton`.

Comment: You can try with MultiValueConerter, see this question that might help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926709/passing-values-to-ivalueconverter?answertab=active#tab-top. you can pass the whole object and pass the parameter as Value1 and/or Value 2. For passing parameters see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978937/how-to-pass-an-integer-as-converterparameter

Comment: @D_Learning - I'm not having any problems with the Converter or parameters to it.

Answer (score 1):

> would like to change the Converter for each RadioButton option,

Create a new MultiValueConverter which takes an extra parameter (the radio button option) and then simply route the call to the appropriate converter based on that option.

One can put the *option* in the `Tag` property on the control's Xaml.

---

### Example

Its not clear to me what that option you mention is, so in my example let us uniquely identify each Radio Button by its `Tag` property and use the routing converter to find the appropriate converter based off of the `Tag` supplied.

```
<RadioButton Tag="1"/><RadioButton Tag="2"/>
```

Then change the style to use the new converter with the new parameter:

```
<Style x:Key="RbVisibilityStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility">
      <Setter.Value>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RouterViaTagVisibilityConverter">
            <Binding Path="Value1"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="Value2"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
            <Binding Path="Tag"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
         </MultiBinding>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sorry, I only gave the one example to keep the question short.  Imagine the exact same RadioButton node with a different say `Rb2Visibility` assigned to the Converter

Comment: @SwDevMan81 At what point would the visibility converter be assigned/re-assigned? Is this to be done in code or a binding?

Comment: Preferably in the binding

Comment: @SwDevMan81, No, I know its in the binding, I mean what triggers the change to change a binding?

Comment: The binding itself would never change.  A change in `Value1` or `Value2` would "trigger" the converter to run and redetermine the Visibility property and update UI accordingly.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 if the binding to a converter never changes, then the suggestion I present about a centralized converter which switches based off a specific controls solves the problem but does not appear to answer you question.

Comment: I would agree,.  Its more of a hack using the Tag property to identify which Button is being clicked and then adding additional logic in a single converter.  It could be useful for someone, but it doesn't solve my problem, thanks for the answer